# How to manage errors when creating an ICEFaces' OutputReource

Tags: java-ee-6, icefaces, websphere-8

I am trying to generate an export file out of some items, which should conform to some "criteria" in order to be able to be exported. The thing is: the user should select some items (by using checkboxes) and then click on the ICEFaces' **OutputResource** in order to export (hopefully all) the selected items.

The parts involved in this process are the following:

The OutputResource in the XHTML:

```
<ice:outputResource rendered="#{not myBackingBean.emptySelection}" resource="#{myBackingBean.excelResource}" label="export to Excel" shared="false" target="_self" />
```

The backing bean holding the resource:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myBackingBean")
@ViewScoped
@WindowDisposed
public class MyBackingBean implements Serializable
{
 ...
 private ExcelResource resource;
 ...
}
```

And, finally, the actual resource:

```
...
import com.icesoft.faces.context.Resource;
...

public class ExcelResource implements Resource
{
  ...

  @Override
  public InputStream open() throws IOException
  {
    //do some selection here. If there is no valid ticket to export then
    //this method will return null, otherwise it will return an InputStream
    //and everything will work properly

    if (everythingOk)
    {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(...);
    }

    //hopefully, it won't get to this point
    return null;
  }
```

As you can see, I'm implementing the `com.icesoft.faces.context.Resource` interface and overriding the `open()` method to create the Excel export "on the fly".

Now, once againg, what I want to do is to filter some of the originally selected items and, in case no item is left, navigate to some error page. If this was an `h:commandButton` or an `ice:commandLink` then I would use the **action** property to do it, but I cannot do this here because this is an `ice:outputResource`. Is there some workaround for this?. Please notice it is not enough to use the **rendered** property to do this because the user can select something (which will immediately render the `ice:outputResource`) but the selection should be filtered before exporting it.

Last but not least: I'm using Websphere 8 and ICEFaces 3 to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could hold the state of each checkbox (as getter/setter pairs) on a 'view' bean. When clicking 'export', you are actually submitting the form, which means that the setters are called before the export code is executed, which means that you can then query the view bean to find out which checkbox is 'on'.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @RazvanPetruescu, but the problem is not to determine which items are selected but to handle the possible scenario where some items are selected but none of them is actually _valid for export_ (in which case, the `OutputResource` should return `null` and the application should redirect to some _error page_).

Anyway, I think I found some alternative using command buttons and I'm editing my own question now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do what I was looking for, this time using some buttons with real **actions** to redirect to pages.

What I did was the following:

- `MyBackingBean` has now a method to determine whether or not the selection is *empty*;
- It also has a method to determine if the selection is *valid* (this is: *not empty* and without any *invalid* item in it);
- There is an `<ice:commandLink>` rendered when the selection is *invalid*. This *commandLink* has the actual redirection to the error page.
- The `<ice:outputResource>` will be rendered when the `<ice:commandLink>` is **not** rendered (i.e.: when the selection is completely **valid**).

And now, the code:

First, the **commandLink**:

```
<ice:commandLink rendered="#{not myBackingBean.validSelection}" 
     disabled="#{myBackingBean.emptySelection}" 
     label="download excel report}"
     action="redirect_to_error_page" />
```

Remember:

- `MyBackingBean.isEmptySelection()` returns *true* if there is no item selected.
- `MyBackingBean.isValidSelection()` returns *true* if there is at least one item selected and also each and every selected item is a *valid* item (this is: an item that is *valid for export*)

Now, the **outputResource**:

```
<ice:outputResource 
    rendered="#{myBackingBean.validSelection}" 
    resource="#{myBackingBean.excelResource}" 
    label="download excel report}" shared="false" target="_self" />
```

Last but not least, you may have figured out the fact that the `<ice:outputResource>` will now handle only *valid* selection (the actual redirection to the error page is being done by the `<ice:commandLink>`). This means there has to be a way to **filter** the items before passing them to the resource for the actual export. Well, in my case I decided to create a `filter(...)` method in the backing bean.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myBackingBean")
@ViewScoped
@WindowDisposed
public class MyBackingBean implements Serializable
{
 ...
 private ExcelResource resource;
 ...

 public List<MyItems> getFilteredList(List<MyItems> allSelectedItems)
 {
  ...
  //do some selection here and return a list containing only valid items
  return validItemsList;
 }

 public ExcelResource getExcelResource()
 {
   return new ExcelResource(getFilteredList(allSelectedItems));
 }

 public boolean isEmptySelection()
 {
   //return true if the selection is EMPTY, false otherwise.
 }

 public boolean isValidSelection()
 {
   //return true if the selection is NOT EMPTY and it has
   //only VALID items in it, false otherwise.
 }
}
```

This way you can generate the `ExcelResource` "on the fly" with nothing but valid items in it. By the time the `<ice:outputResource>` is being rendered in the XHTML, it will contain only valid and exportable items!.

I hope someone will find this useful :)